# During a Wifi/3g/GSM wireless download, what transmissions are made by the downloading party?

Tags: wireless-networking, 3g, hsdpa

I realise the answer may depend on which wireless technology we are talking about. Information on any of the above would be interesting. I am interested in knowing if there are continuous transmissions in both directions. Its my understanding that there would be one tcp ack for each receive window. What sort of size TCP 'receive windows' do these kinds of connections use?

Answer (score 1):

[RFC3481](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3481) may be relavent here. ACKs will need to be transmitted from the receiver. Fewer may be necessary if you work around the normal TCP [slow start](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slow-start) behavior by using a large initial window (number of bytes in-flight, not yet ACKnowledged).

Comment: Thanks, after reading that I'm still not sure though if its up to the client to report missing packets, or whether they are all acknowledged and resent if theres no ack. Both situations appear to be described. I'm also wondering if there is a radio transmission of any kind during idle time ie when there's no data to send or receive.